# How to rename queue in Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using `Rabbitmq 3.7.17` and I need to rename an existing queue that already contains some messages. Is there a simple way to rename a queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't rename a queue. If you have to keep the messages, follow these steps.

- Create the new queue.
- Bind it to the exchange as the old queue was bound.
- Unbind the old queue from the exchange.
- Consume the messages from the old queue and republish them to the exchange. This will route the messages to the new queue.
- Once all messages in the old queue have been consumed, delete it.

Comment: This approach has a number of drawbacks:  

- New events can be added from the exchange to the new queue out-of-order with the republished events  
- All queues bound to the exchange will get the republished events, surely out-of-order

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @user11044402 already recommended, once you created the queue under its NEW name, use the  `RabbitMQ Shovel` plugin if it is installed to move all the messages from the queue with the old name to the new queue. Then delete the old queue - the shovel will be automatically removed as well.